# How can I index a randomly generated element on a printed array in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a text based pacman-type game using multiple array printing. The user needs to control the pacman character using inputs. Now, the character is randomly generated across a 20x10 grid that's made up of the dash symbol (-). How am I able to index the position of the character once it gets randomly printed so that I can make it move using a player's input?

Here is my code so far:

```
w, h = 20, 10
separator = ' '

two_d_array = [['-' for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)]

coins = random.sample(range(w * h), 10)
character = random.sample(range(w * h), 1)

for s in coins:
    row = int(s/w)
    column = s % w
    two_d_array[row][column] = 'o'
    
for t in character:
    row = int(t/w)
    column = t % w
    two_d_array[row][column] = 'c'

for grid in two_d_array:
    print(separator.join(grid))
```

The character is represented using the letter c here.

Comment: that is unclear, you want to save the positions ?

Comment: yes, I want to save the position of the printed 'c' so that I can do other functions to it.

Comment: Use a list, and save the tuple of coordinates `mylist.append((row, column))` ?

Comment: The position of the `c` is controlled by `two_d_array[row = int(t/w)][column = t % w]`  ... so  those two calculations already encode the player position ... if you move your player you adjust your single value inside the character list (up/down is += width, left/right is +-=1 - you need to fix it if you go out of bounds so it flips to the other side (or prevent the movement )) .... I dont get what you want to store in addition to `character[0]` - (also dont get why you store it in a list)

Comment: MAybe you should change to tuples to remove the recalculation steps:  `coins = list (zip(random.sample(range(w), 10),random.sample(range(h), 10))` .. or even do a `def get_rand_pos(max_w, max_h): return random.choice(range(max_w)), random.choice(range(max_h))` and use that instead (although less "performant" maybe more clear)

Comment: How can I pop each individual coins? Knowing there are 10 of them generated each time, once a player eats a coin in the game, I'm thinking I should pop the coin and replace it with `c`